# LocalStorage delete items after exit javascript cordova

Tags: cordova, local-storage

i have an app that have some variables which is saved via localstorage on the device. I build my app via `cordova run android` everthing works great and the variables should be saved. After i exit the app and start it again the saved variables should loaded automatically but that does not happen.. 
How i save them after exit the app.

```
function onBackKeyDown() {
    localStorage.setItem("codeCounter", codeCounter);
    localStorage.setItem("geoLocation", geoLocation);
    localStorage.setItem("timeStamp", timeStamp);
    navigator.app.exitApp();
}
```

And how i load them.

```
window.onload = checkCounter;
function checkCounter() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("codeCounter") == null
            || isNaN(localStorage.getItem("codeCounter"))) {
        codeCounter = 0;
    } else {
        codeCounter = localStorage.getItem("codeCounter");
    }
    if (localStorage.getItem("geoLocation") == null) {
        geoLocation = "0";
    } else {
        geoLocation = localStorage.getItem("geoLocation");
    }
    if (localStorage.getItem("timeStamp") == null) {
        timeStamp = "1";
    } else {
        timeStamp = localStorage.getItem("timeStamp");
    }
}
```

But after i exit the app and start it again, the app does not load the variables from the localstorage. Why ? :/

Answer (score 0):

Try `localStorage.setItem("key",JSON.stringify(Value))` when storing and `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Key"))` when accessing the values.